# Reg back button behavior in android

Tags: android

I am having a specific problem in my android app. I have 2 activities and the flow is from 
Activity 1 to Activity 2.

I press back button from Activity 2 and then it goes to activity 1. This is great. But in some devices if I stay too long on activity 2(Like for days, I check it once in a while ) , and when I press back button it doesn't go back. So I guess history is cleared by android os for getting more memory.

I know that I can manually override onBackPressed() and achieve the functionality, but I need a perfect solution for this. so it will be like 
If the history is all right let android handle back, If history is disturbed then I should be able to handle it.

IS there any way to check any issue with history?

Comment: *But in some devices if I stay too long on activity 2, and when I press back button it doesn't go back.* hearing this for the first time. :)

Comment: @LittleChild I meant like after 2 days and all. As far as I know android stores the activity which should be resumed on click of back, but it clears that if its in need of memory. Right?

Comment: So what exactly happens? You exit the app directly?

Comment: @LittleChild no the app is not responding when I press back button from activity 2